# Angular - The problem with directly assigning a value from the service to a variable in the class

Tags: angular

For some time I have been having a problem with injecting a service into a component in my Angular application and assigning its value directly to a variable in the class.

I want to assign the value from the service to a variable in the component class using the following code:

```
test.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  get(): number {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

```
test.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  providers: [TestService]
})
export class TestComponent {

  value: number = this.testService.get();

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

}
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

When I do the below everything works fine.:

```
...
export class TestComponent {

  value: number;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
     this.value = this.testService.get();
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

I should also mention that I am using Angular 15.2.4 and did not encounter this issue in previous versions.

Best regards,
Greg

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to do it your way. Can you reproduce the error in a new project in stackblitz for example?

Comment: I found a problem. The missing element is the lack of definition for useDefineForClassFields in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

I believe the issue is trying to get access to a function that lives in a service and hasn't been handled entirely, the component does not yet have that dependency injected or resolved.

It is a good practice to handle all initialization logic on `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

You could also use the new `inject` feature from `Angular` which also handles dependency injection as a function, is an alternative for `constructors`.

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  private service: TestService = inject(TestService);
  myValue = this.service.get();
}
```

I recommend reading the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) understanding the multiple Angular lifecycle hooks.

Comment: My solution probably won't work in ES2022 or later versions without the useDefineForClassFields flag set to true, so your solution is more appropriate in such cases. I was wondering what could be causing this error. However, I managed to find the answer and added the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of searching, I found the problem.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

When I updated and changed the target to ES2022 in tsconfig.json, the **useDefineForClassFields** flag has the default value set to true.

The problem disappeared when I added this flag to tsconfig.json and set:

```
"useDefineForClassFields": false
```

I noticed that a newly created project on the latest version of angular-cli@15 this flag is also added to tsconfig.json.

Details about the flag can be found here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields

Thanks for trying to help! I appreciate!

Comment: You saved the day